# Prevent duplicates from being added to Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, recursion, nodes, binary-search-tree

**This is homework. Please don't give me just code.**

The assignment was to implement several methods that a BST uses; among those, was `add(T data)` and `remove(T data)`. I was able to successfully implement them.

Here were the guidelines for the two methods:

- `public void add(T data)`

  - If the data was already in the tree, do nothing (no duplicates)
  - Must be recursive (I created a helper function)
- `public T remove(T data)`

  - If the data wasn't in the tree, `throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()`
  - Must be recursive (I created a helper function)

I had originally coded it up so it used the `contains(T data)` method to check how to add/remove the data. I found out that I can't use the `contains()` method to do this, and that I must implement it some other way.

Conceptually, I understand that I need to essentially check if we're at a parent node with no leaves. However, I'm not entirely sure *where* or *how* to implement these checks.

For example, here are my `add()` methods:

```
@Override
public void add(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data is null");
    }
    //FIXME don't use the contains() method
    if (root == null) {
        BSTNode<T> node = new BSTNode<>(data);
        root = node;
    } else {
        addRec(root, data);
    }
    size++;
}

/**
 * Helper method to recursively add data to the BST
 * @param node is the node we're currently at
 * @param data is the data we're adding to the BST
 * @return node that we added
 */
private BSTNode<T> addRec(BSTNode<T> node, T data) {
    //This if-statement isn't correct
    if (compare(data, node.getLeft().getData()) == 0
        || compare(data, node.getRight().getData()) == 0) {
        return node;
    }

    if (node == null) {
        return new BSTNode<T>(data);
    }
    if (compare(data, node.getData()) == 0) {
        return node;
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) < 0) {
        node.setLeft(addRec(node.getLeft(), data));
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) > 0) {
        node.setRight(addRec(node.getRight(), data));
    }
    return node;
}

@Override
public boolean contains(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data is null");
    }
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return containsRec(root, data);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to recursively check if the BST contains the data
 * @param  node is the node we're currently at
 * @param  data is the data we're looking for
 * @return boolean if the data was found
 */
private boolean containsRec(BSTNode<T> node, T data) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) < 0) {
        return containsRec(node.getLeft(), data);
    } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) > 0) {
        return containsRec(node.getRight(), data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private int compare(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

If I can figure out this one, I'm pretty sure fixing the `remove()` methods will be nearly the same.

*Test that is failing* (There are several)

```
@Test
public void testAddDuplicate() {
    // setup
    makeTree();

    // add duplicates
    bst.add(bst.getRoot().getData());
    bst.add(bst.getRoot().getLeft().getData());
    bst.add(bst.getRoot().getRight().getData());

    // check size
    assertEquals(9, bst.size());
}
```

Comment: `if(compare(data, node.getData()) == 0) {return node;}` - do you know what this does?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I actually forgot to add a bit of code in. I edited the OP.

Comment: But do you realize that it answers the question in your title?

Comment: Oh. Uh. No--no I didn't. How? I realizes that it essentially checks if the value is in the tree--however, I'm still failing JUnit tests my professor supplied if I remove a check for `(!contains(data))`. If I have everything like the above code, and remove that incorrect if-statement--it still won't work.

Comment: Can we see the test that's failing, and the contains method?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added both to the OP.

Comment: Please don't heavily edit questions once you have answers.  I've rolled back the edit here and on two of your other questions.

Comment: @Nxt3 One question per question, and don't change the question after someone answers it. I'll undo that edit. (Btw, edits are fine to questions as long as they don't change the question, so fixing typos or adding clarification is fine)

Comment: As has just been pointed out, heavily editing the content of questions that are already answered is not acceptable. Please stop.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're seriously not going to remove these posts? I flagged them for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (root == null) {
    BSTNode<T> node = new BSTNode<>(data);
    root = node;
} else {
    addRec(root, data);
}
size++;
```

In this code, you increment `size` whether or not a duplicate element was found or whether or not the tree was actually changed.  Therefore the unit test is (correctly) identifying that the `size` of your tree has changed, even though the tree only has the right number of elements.

You should only increment `size` when you actually add a new node to the tree.

Comment: But how? How am I to know whether or not the node was added?

Comment: Well, you could increment `size` directly when you create the new node in `addRec`, rather than at the top level.

Comment: That fixes one thing. :) Thank you. I didn't think about adding the size there.

Comment: Do you have any insights on my `remove()` method? I've updated the OP.

Comment: That looks complex enough to possibly be a different question?

Comment: It probably is. I was trying to avoid spamming SO.

Answer (score 2):

Implement ***one*** of the three ways to traverse a binary tree namely In Order, Pre Order, or Post Order.

Leverage this method to determine whether your tree contains a given item. In case of add, you don't need to do anything. In case of remove, you can remove that node from the tree.

Comment: Part of the assignment was to implement all three of those, and level-order traversal. However, I can't do this due to the constraint that the big-O can't exceed (worse case) O(n). If I used any of those methods as leverage, it will increase the Big-O. Furthermore, you certainly have to handle something with the `add()` method; if I just remove checking `(!contains(data))`, it will fail the JUnit test I was given.

Comment: You don't need to search the entire tree to find out if something is in it. Otherwise what exactly would be the point of it?

Comment: I see your point EJP and agree with it.You need to implement a search method (with a complexity of O(ln) i.e. log base 2  of n, where n is number of nodes in the tree). That way you don't have to traverse the hole tree O(n).

Comment: @user1521213 @EJP I'm sorry, that's what I meant. Here. I've updated the OP with my `contains()` method just so we're all on the same page. It doesn't matter why, but I'm *not* allowed to reuse `contains()` to check if the data already exists when adding or if the data doesn't exist when removing.

Comment: @EJP The `add()` method's Java Doc: *Should have a running time of O(log n) for a balanced, and a worst case of O(n).*

Comment: @Nxt3 Exactly my point. You don't need to search the entire tree, except of course in the degenerate case, and you certainly don't need to do it separately when the `add()` method is *already* searching the tree to find the insertion point.